# ERROR: 'Client' object has no attribute 'torrents_add'

Tags: python

```
import os
import time
from pyrogram.types import Message
from qbittorrent import Client as cli
from tg_bot import LOG

def download_magnet(link: str, message: Message) -> dict:
    try:
        # Connect to the qBittorrent client
        qb = cli('https://127.0.0.0')
        qb.login('admin', 'adminadmin')  # Replace 'adminadmin' with your actual password

        # Add the magnet link to the client
        qb.torrents_add(urls=link)
        qb.torrents_reannounce()

        # Notify the start of the download
        LOG.info(f"Starting download of {link}")
        message.edit_text(f"Starting download of {link}")

        # Record the start time
        begin = time.time()

        # Wait until the torrent is completed
        while qb.torrents()[0]['state'] != 'completed':
            # Get current torrent status
            status = qb.torrents()[0]['state']
            progress = qb.torrents()[0]['progress']
            download_speed = qb.torrents()[0]['dlspeed']
            upload_speed = qb.torrents()[0]['upspeed']
            num_peers = qb.torrents()[0]['num_seeds']
            
            LOG.info('%.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kB/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d) %s' % (progress * 100, download_speed / 1024, upload_speed / 1024, num_peers, status))
            message.edit_text('%.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kB/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d) %s' % (progress * 100, download_speed / 1024, upload_speed / 1024, num_peers, status))
            
            time.sleep(10)

        # Get the list of torrents
        torrents = qb.torrents()

        # Get the name of the added torrent
        torrent_name = torrents[0]['name']

        # Record the end time
        end = time.time()

        # Calculate elapsed time
        elapsed_min = int((end - begin) // 60)
        elapsed_sec = int((end - begin) % 60)

        # Get the download path
        download_path = os.path.join(qb.app.default_save_path, torrent_name)

        # Notify completion with elapsed time
        LOG.info('Torrent download complete.')
        message.edit_text(f'Torrent download complete. Elapsed Time: {elapsed_min} min : {elapsed_sec} sec. Now uploading.')

        return {"file": download_path, "name": torrent_name}

    except Exception as e:
        LOG.error(e)
        return None
```

i was trying to make a telegram bot but its saying ERROR: 'Client' object has no attribute 'torrents_add'

Comment: which python package did you use,  there appears to be multiple.